# Node.js: "express" не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом

Tags: javascript, node.js, cmd, npm, express

Здравствуйте, работаю на Windows 7.
Поставил express и express-generator:

```
npm i -g express
npm i -g express-generator
```

Версии:

```
express-generator@4.14.1
express@4.15.2
```

Установил NODE_PATH:

```
setx NODE_PATH %AppData%\npm\node_modules
```

И всё равно при запуске команды:

```
express -h
```

консоль выдаёт сообщение:

```
"express" не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чём может быть проблема.

Comment: а какой результат вы ожидаете?

Comment: покажите, что у вас в переменной **PATH**

Comment: Да, дело было в PATH, добавил путь до npm: C:\Users\currentuser\AppData\Roaming\npm и всё заработало, спасибо) @MikhailVaysman

Comment: я дополнил ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Express глобально не нужен, только express-generator.
Я неделю как переустановил Windows7(32bit), и вот сейчас дай, думаю, кстати и генератор заготовлю: написал npm install -g express-generator и через 10 секунд, тут же, написал express -h - и все опции мне благополучно вывел.

Короче, даже сказать нечего. Попробуйте их npm uninstall -g ... , перезагрузитесь, да и установите ещё раз генератор. Всё должно работать.

А, и NODE_PATH никакой устанавливать не нужно. Тем более что папка с генератором находится по пути %AppData%\Roaming\npm После установки express-generator в переменной PATH среды юзера (верхнее окошко) должен быть прописан такой путь c:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm

Comment: Вы правы, только после установки express-generator путь %AppData%\Roaming\npm в переменной PATH автоматически не прописался, добавил ручками и всё заработало, спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

Если все установилось правильно, то вы можете создать файл **server.js** с таким содержимым

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World')
})

app.listen(3000)
```

И запустить его

```
node server.js
```

После этого в браузере открыть [localhost:3000](http://localhost:3000) и увидеть **Hello World**

Так же проверьте, что у вас правильно установлена переменная **PATH**. Она должна содержать путь к тому месту, где находятся все исполняемые файлы для **node**.

Comment: Речь именно об [утилите `express`](http://expressjs.com/ru/starter/generator.html).